# How to : executing a block of code every 24 hours in a server?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, web

I want to fetch certain data from website every 24 hours. The code must be executed every 24 hours and update the MySQL database. How can I accomplish this without any user events?

Later i'll use same data to find the total difference.

totalIncrement = currentData - earlierData

While earlierData is fetched from the MySQl database and current data is fetched from the external website query.

I've heard of a cron on linux but have never tried it. Can any body just give a basic idea for that? or any reliable link?

May be i want to do it like this::

First create a PHP program/file that does the fetching job.
Second execute that PHP file every 24 hours or so...

Comment: A cronjob is definitely what you're looking for.  There are tons of resources on the internet explaining what they are and how to use them.  You can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron.

Comment: Have you even tried Google for tutorials on Cron jobs? C'mon, man - you have to at least make an effort.

Comment: @Lucanos. In order to google Cron job, you need to know that it is called a 'cron job'.  It was not **THAT** obvious when I switched to Linux.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: Agreed, but in his actual question he **mentioned** "cron" - "*I've heard of a cron on linux but have never tried it.*" So it's not as though he had nothing to work from.

Answer (score 2):

Open a shell. 
(*Stop crond service **service crond stop***)
Use vi (or other editor) to edit cron file or type "**crontab -e**" to make your edit.
After edit hit "**ESC**". Then "**:wq**", to save and quit.
(*Start the service again **service crond start***)
Stopping and starting the service is not needed if you use crontab -e.

Your script should be running by now.
Check the syntax [here](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) or [here](http://www.talis.com/services/docs/sysman/webhelp/scripts/cron_command_syntax.htm).
To view the changes you've made type "**crontab -l**".

I hope this helps.

Comment: -1: cron neither needs root access (it is allowed to most users by default) nor a restart of the daemon to pick up new crontab files. Also, you are effectively telling people how to use "vi". of course crontab -e does not (necessarily) use "vi", it can use any editor in the VISUAL environment variable. Some distributions use another editor by default.

Comment: crontab -e MAY invoke "vi", depending on how it's configured. You don't need to restart the service in this case; it's usable by non-root users.

Comment: In real life, you have to stop the service to make any changes because many of the scripts are codependent. For example changes to a table other script reads.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to ignore the advice to start and stop the cron daemon when editing a crontab(5).  The crontab(1) utility notifies the cron daemon that the crontab(5) file needs to be reread and changes will take affect immediately.  The only reason you would ever need to restart the cron daemon is if you edited the crontab(5) file directly without the crontab(1) utility.

Comment: Please consider writing a comment to the answer that this relates to. I think your points are valid though.

Answer (score -3):

First you will have to make a php file for this example cron.php

So whenever you go to this link www.yourdomain.com/crom.php the script is executed

Now add this link in cron job. To set up cron job on your server you can us [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1189-PHP-Schedule-cron-jobs-with-ease-.html) class of php

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting without explaining what he said was wrong?